# use of phpmailer class

Tags: php, phpmailer

i m using phpmailer class for sending emails. i m geeting error "Could not execute: /smtp" the following code  the code is below. can someone suggest me what is the problem.

```
require '../class.phpmailer.php'; 

try {
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true); //New instance, with exceptions enabled

    $body             = file_get_contents('contents.html');
    echo $body;
    $body             = preg_replace('/\\\\/','', $body); //Strip backslashes

    $mail->IsSMTP();                           // tell the class to use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Port       = 25;                    // set the SMTP server port
    $mail->Host       = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server
    $mail->Username   = "test@gmail.com";     // SMTP server username
    $mail->Password   = "1234567889";            // SMTP server password

    $mail->IsSendmail();  // tell the class to use Sendmail

    $mail->AddReplyTo("rto@gmail.com","First Last");

    $mail->From       = "from@gmail.com";
    $mail->FromName   = "First Last";

    $to = "toemail@gmail.com";

    $mail->AddAddress($to);

    $mail->Subject  = "First PHPMailer Message";

    $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
    $mail->WordWrap   = 80; // set word wrap

    $mail->MsgHTML($body);

    $mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML

    $mail->Send();
    echo 'Message has been sent.';
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage();
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting exactly in which line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using GMail, your settings might likely not be correct; try these (corrected port and SSL address):

```
$mail->Port       =  465;                   // set the SMTP server port
$mail->Host       = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->Username   = "test@gmail.com";       // SMTP server username
$mail->Password   = "1234567889";
```

Alternatively, use TLS:

```
$mail->Port       =  587;                   // set the SMTP server port
$mail->Host       = "tls://smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server
```

---

**Edit**: Remove this line below (You first provide settings to use SMTP, then you tell it to use and send trough sendmail and you put a wrong path in configs. Just stick to one service, use SMTP with above settings (or edit2 below) and see):

Remove:

```
$mail->IsSendmail();  // tell the class to use Sendmail
```

---

**Edit2:** other option (in case the first answer don't work):

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
```

Comment: i changed the code but still the problem remains.Could not execute: /smtp

Comment: @Deepa you should give us further information, then, stating clearly the error message your receive.

Comment: in class.phpmailer.php,  public function IsSendmail() {
    if (!stristr(ini_get('sendmail_path'), 'sendmail')) {
      $this->Sendmail = '/var/qmail/bin/sendmail';
    }
    $this->Mailer = 'sendmail';
  }
i just changed the sendmail path to '/smtp'.

Comment: @Deepa Updated answer, remove the IsSendmail line

Comment: if i remove $mail->IsSendmail(); then new error "SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. "

Comment: @Deepa Did you also try using the settings I provided in Edit2? (adding SMTP secure and changing the host). The port is correct, I usually use ssl://... when connecting to gmail and always work, though...Email and password are correct?

Comment: @Deepa try with ssl://smtp.gmail.com instead of what I wrote before (see I have corrected my answer)

Comment: but i m geetting path problem Could not execute: //var/qmail/bin/sendmail. is these are linked really

Comment: @Deepa but are you on a localhost?